# Call Method Outside Class

Tags: java

So I am trying to call a method I have in a different class.

It's a simple task, and I have looked at many tutorials and other posts on here, but for some reason I just can't get it to work.

Here is the first class

```
public class ArrayProcessor {

   public void print3IntArray(int[] array) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         System.out.println("Entry " + i + " is " + array[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

I first tried

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayProgram {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Random rand = new Random();

   int[] anArray = new int[3];

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         int random = rand.nextInt(11);
         anArray[i] = random;
      }
   }
   ArrayProcessor.print3IntArray(anArray);
}
```

But then after looking at some posts on this website I tried

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayProgram {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   ArrayProcessor ap = new ArrayProcessor();

   Random rand = new Random();

   int[] anArray = new int[3];

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         int random = rand.nextInt(11);
         anArray[i] = random;
      }
   }
   ap.print3IntArray(anArray);
}
```

Both codes give me the following error:

```
ArrayProgram.java:21: error: <identifier> expected
   ap.print3IntArray(anArray);
                    ^
ArrayProgram.java:21: error: <identifier> expected
   ap.print3IntArray(anArray);
                            ^
2 errors
```

Comment: typo: move the `}` before the call to `print3IntArray` after that statement. Closing...

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum where you can ask for closing the question (except it is off-topic). Since the provided answer has an upvote you have to live with this question. (repost to fix typos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this

```
ap.print3IntArray(anArray);
```

after the closing curly brace of the `main` method, so your code actually does not reside in any method or container block of code, which is unacceptable by the compiler. Change

```
} // closing curly brace of main()
ap.print3IntArray(anArray);
```

to

```
    ap.print3IntArray(anArray);
} // closing curly brace of main()
```

Comment: That hurts, just seeing that. Well, you're right I can see that now, and it was definitely the problem. Both options I developed worked! I will give you the answer, once the time restriction is lifted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call
`ArrayProcessor.print3IntArray(anArray);`
 outside a method (in this case main method) but if you want to call it inside the main method then make the function print3IntArray static in ArrayProcessor class.

```
public class ArrayProcessor{
    public static void print3IntArray(int[] array) 
      {
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Entry " + i + " is " + array[i]);
      }   
}
```